# usage of "as + adjective"

Tags: prepositions, as, predicative-complement

Consider:

> All cases involving children are treated **as** urgent.
>
> The man was described **as** tall and dark, and aged about 20.

How "as" can collocate with adjectives here?

If I omitted "as" or replaced "as" with "to be", would these two examples still be correct and acceptable?

Comment: why not? I consider him *as mad*! And an answer to all your questions is Yes! though some may look informal.

Comment: I perfectly understand these sentences, and I just want a syntactic analysis.

Comment: I guess that my rigid adherence to the rules sometimes really is annoying. Anyway, I was taught in this way like in other Asian countries. I think it's kind of failure and frustrasting. At least the questions I have asked will do good to learners like me.

Comment: @MaulikV 'I consider him ***as*** mad; is grammatically incorrect. It should be 'I consider him to be mad'

Comment: @AdilAli *...are beginning to consider **him as mad.*** from **Promises, Promises: Essay on Psychoanalysis and Literature.** - Google Books! :)

Comment: @AdilAli Another one from the Australian (Govt) Newspaper - http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/65714021

Comment: "As is sometimes used superfluously to introduce the complements of verbs like consider, deem, and account: They considered it as one of the landmark decisions of the civil rights movement. The measure was deemed as unnecessary. 

 This usage may have arisen by analogy to regard and esteem, where as is standardly used in this way: We regarded her as the best writer among us. But the use of as with verbs like consider is not sufficiently well established to be acceptable in writing." -The American Heritage Book of English Usage

Comment: **grammatically incorrect** means it **does not exist** at all! Controversial or not well established is altogether a different thing.

Comment: Okay, but it doesn't sound right. Maybe I'll edit my comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's try removing 'described as'. We get these sentences:

> All cases involving children are urgent.
>
> The man was tall and dark, and aged about 20.

You can see here that the sentences have a different meaning. This **confirms** that the cases are urgent and the man was tall and dark. By adding in the 'treated as' or the 'described as' we show how these adjectives are only applied in certain conditions.

To add the 'described as' in the second sentence is to say that the man *may not be* tall or dark, but someone *had described him* that way. The cases involving children may not be urgent, but we *treat them* that way.

It's not the 'as' that it is important here. The verb before it is what you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

> All cases involving children are treated as urgent.
>
> The man was described as tall and dark, and aged about 20.

In both the sentences, 'as' collocates with the ***verb***, not the adjectives.
'Describe as' is used when you are actually describing someone, not just referring to the act of description.'Treated as' is used to show how the person/thing concerned are being treated. Omitting 'as' therefore would render the sentence incorrect.
'To be' cannot replace 'as', as they mean different things, and are different parts of speech.
Adding 'being' would not change the meaning of the sentence, though it may emphasise the adjective.

Comment: I knew 'as' collocates with the verb, but I wonder how "as urgent" can act as subject-complement here. I would think it should be a noun. Preposition can't take an adjective as its object.

Comment: Prepositions do not take anything as their objects, verbs do.

Comment: I might think we have greatly different framework on grammar. @Adil Ali

Comment: Different framework of grammar? We are talking about the same language, how on earth can we have a different framework?

Comment: To the downvoter, can you tell me why you downvoted?

Comment: That's why we differ much on this.

Comment: Actually, I didn't do it. Somebody else did it. I swear to god.

Comment: I never said that you did it. I wanted to know why whoever did it, did it. They must explain so that if they think I am wrong they can correct me.